# Codeigniter: How to include javascript files

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, include

Hello I just started working with CodeIgniter framework. My current directory structure is

```
Demo(Project name)
 +System
 +Application
   -Controllers
      demo.php
   +Model
   -Views
      view_demo.php
 -Js
    ajax.js
    jquery.js
```

Please tell me how to include .js files in view_demo.php.

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to use the `base_url()` to include the javascript file in your VIEW.

So, in the view_demo.php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>js/jquery.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>js/ajax.js" ></script>
```

You will need the URL helper loaded. To load the helper you need to put on your demo.php controller:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

You can also autoload on \config\autoload.php on the helpers array.

More info about base_url(): http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#short-open-tags

Comment: Thank you Isern Palaus. I tried this but base_url() is echoing "http://example.com/" and giving file not found error for those .js files. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post your controller and your view? If base_url() shows your url its right. You've to configure your BASE URL on the file config.php on directory config, its very important!

Comment: Thank you Isern. Actually I did not set config['base_url'] in config.php file to my project url. I just did that.

Comment: Hey! a bit late but...
site_url("path/to/your/asset") will return your base url followed by the path you specify. I think that's cleaner than concatenating manually using base_url() but both get the work done.

Answer (score 22):

You wouldn't include JS files within the PHP, they would be output as script tags within the HTML you produce which you may be producing as output from the PHP script.

As far as I know, there is no built in CodeIginiter function to include this output like there is for CSS using the `link_tag()` function provided by CI.  I've added a function called `script_tag()` to the `system/helpers/html_helper.php` file from CI.  The function is:

```
if ( ! function_exists('script_tag')) {
    function script_tag($src = '', $language = 'javascript', $type = 'text/javascript', $index_page = FALSE)
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $script = '<scr'.'ipt';
        if (is_array($src)) {
            foreach ($src as $k=>$v) {
                if ($k == 'src' AND strpos($v, '://') === FALSE) {
                    if ($index_page === TRUE) {
                        $script .= ' src="'.$CI->config->site_url($v).'"';
                    }
                    else {
                        $script .= ' src="'.$CI->config->slash_item('base_url').$v.'"';
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $script .= "$k=\"$v\"";
                }
            }

            $script .= "></scr"."ipt>\n";
        }
        else {
            if ( strpos($src, '://') !== FALSE) {
                $script .= ' src="'.$src.'" ';
            }
            elseif ($index_page === TRUE) {
                $script .= ' src="'.$CI->config->site_url($src).'" ';
            }
            else {
                $script .= ' src="'.$CI->config->slash_item('base_url').$src.'" ';
            }

            $script .= 'language="'.$language.'" type="'.$type.'"';
            $script .= ' /></scr'.'ipt>'."\n";
        }
        return $script;
    }
}
```

Then in your PHP code you can do:

```
echo script_tag('content/js/jquery-1.4.2.js');
```

Comment: I've also a function like that, http://blog.ipalaus.es/codeigniter-html-helper-modificado-anade-javascript-facilmente , it's very useful! :)

Comment: @ipalaus: Thank you! I have used it in my application and it works great!

Comment: still this solution helping to codeIgniter users. I don't know why community is not adding this method in their next versions. Anyway thanks for the workout. :)

Answer (score 11):

I store my javascript in a subdirectory of my view folder so the file path is relative to the view being called and I omit the base_url().

Another technique I adopted was to define an array of scripts to include in my controller, then loop through the array in my view to include them.  This allows me to include specialty js functions only when needed.

```
$data['scripts to load'] = array('edit.js', 'menu.js', 'contact.js');
$this->load->view('myview');
```

Then in the view

```
 <?php foreach($scripts_to_load as $script):?>
     <script type='text/javascript' src = 'my_js/<?php echo $script;?>'>
 <?php endforeach;?>
```

If you have script files that get loaded on every page, you can hard code them in your footer view like is described in the other answers.

Comment: Do I have to configure any thing before doing this?

Comment: Remember, CI is just PHP.  We're not using any CI functions here beyond loading the view.  It is the same as including js files with script tags.  This array technique just allows more dynamic loading of special javascript files.  That way you only load what you need on each page, keeping your http requests smaller.

Comment: Love this solution.  I will actually use it for something else but its great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The $data variable sometimes may be lost if you have nested views and you don't pass it as an argument to the children/nested views.

I found a simple solution that is working very smoothly to me:

In your current view file you setup your script like this:

$this->scripts[] = '/js/myscript.js';

at your footer or {whatever.php} file you insert this code:

```
    <?php
        if(isset($this->scripts))
        foreach($this->scripts as $script) :
     ?>
            <script src="my_asset_path/js/<?=$script;?>"></script>
    <?endforeach;?>
```

If you need only a pice of javascript code, you can always use anonymous functions like this:

```
<?php
$this->RenderScript[] = function() {
?>
      <script>
        console.log('myjavascript code snippet');
      </script>
<?}?>
```

and at the bottom:

```
<?php
        if(isset($this->RenderScript))
            foreach($this->RenderScript as $script) {
                $script();
            }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the standard:

```
<script src="/path/to/file.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

inside your view! (Not inside the PHP tags, of course.) I don't think the CodeIgniter HTML helper has any functions that you could use as an alternative to writing out the HTML yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Phil Sturgeon's [CodeIgniter Template Library](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template).  We use a modified version of it at work.