# How to load assets in Code Igniter such as JS files and CSS files

Tags: php, codeigniter

Given the file structure and using WAMP

```
www
   application
       \views
           \templates
               header.php
   assets
       \js
          index.js
       \css
          index.css
```

I was trying to follow along the example given in this solution, [Codeigniter: How to include javascript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841286/codeigniter-how-to-include-javascript-files), however I have been unsuccessful.

header.php

```
<html>
    <head>
            <?php $this->load->helper('url');?>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/index.js" ></script>
            <title>CodeIgniter Tutorial</title>

    </head>
    <body>


            <h1><?php echo $title ?></h1>
```

the error thrown in the browser is

```
GET http://localhost/index.php/localhost/assets/js/index.js 404 (Not Found)
```

header.php is being called, as it's the my only php file with a js reference, sorry if I misinterpreted the other guy's solution I really can't understand why it's not working

Comment: So this is what coming as your base url `http://localhost/index.php/localhost/` which seems like not correct.

Comment: Try to access `http://localhost/index.php/assets/js/index.js` and see if it is coming fine?

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'localhost'; just tried accessing http://localhost/index.php/assets/js/index.js with src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/index.js"; no luck

Comment: Try this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/js/index.js"></script>`

Comment: BTW what is site url in your config file?

Comment: There isn't/wasn't a 'site_url' key for the $config array in my config.php file, CI 3.0.0 (current). Closest thing is 'base_url' which is set to 'localhost',

Comment: Can you please echo `site_url()` and see what it is coming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate your `httpd.conf` file.

In my case it is located in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf`

Please uncomment `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

In your config.php located in `application\config\config.php` set the following value.

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

One of the reason to answer why I uncomment `mod_rewrite.so`, [here's the explaination](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/):

Comment: thanks a lot, if you don't mind for future ref can you explain your sol a bit

Answer (score 2):

On `constants.php` below `config.php`

Open `constants.php` and write a piece of this code for your ease

```
define('ROUTE_STIE_PATH','`http://localhost/yoursitename/`');
define('ADMIN_CSS_DIR_FULL_PATH',ROUTE_STIE_PATH.'assets/css/');
define('ADMIN_JS_DIR_FULL_PATH',ROUTE_STIE_PATH.'assets/js/');
```

on header

```
<script src="<?php echo ADMIN_JS_DIR_FULL_PATH; ?>index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: changed to <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url();?>assets/js/index.js" ></script>;

error: GET http://localhost/index.php/localhost/index.phpassets/js/index.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Look at the answer of mine ... on your config.php ..
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/xxxxxx/';

at last you have to have / sign there if not place it there

Comment: i'll try it in a bit, for now @CharlesLiam answer worked fine

Comment: I think its a good way for long purpose to do on my way ..if it works for u