# color picker plugin script import cause unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to import `color picker plugin (http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/)` into the backend of `easyappointments.org`, I follow the plugin documentation and the example page, but for a strange reason when I insert the script to the head of the backend page I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <                   jquery.js:1

this is my structure of import:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="application/third_party/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

if you want see the complete code check [this link](http://pastebin.com/X6zc1Qbq).

The code is too long, sorry if I not pasted here. 
How can I figure out what is causing this problem? I am a bit 'rusty with js and this problem is stopping me a little'

**UPDATE jquery content:**

http://pastebin.com/ee01ifzh

Comment: Have you tried to remote that line? I am curious to know if it would have a similar error with the following line. You said the problem occurs when you put the script tag in the head. Does it mean that it works in the body?

Comment: The script workin in remote, as the demo content provided by the author. Check my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
After some [detailed discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/91905) of the problem, we found the correct solution:

the inclusion of the `CSS` and `JavaScript` files was wrong. All `CSS` and `JS` files need to be [placed in a js folder in the project root,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841286/codeigniter-how-to-include-javascript-files) as the `third_party` folder is [for php extensions only](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/packages.html).

Inclusion order was also important. When including JavaScript, make sure to include the most basic scripts first. In this case, begin with `JQuery`, follow up with additional libraries like `timepicker` and include your own `js` last.

Comment: I've paste the content of js file, anyway, the plugin working on the demo provided by the author. So I don't know what exaclty cause this, probably an incompatibility with the other script?

Comment: Hum, the Script seems fine. Did you try removing the live, as @Sindico suggested? Do you get the same error? Also, did you check, that the pasted file is the file included by the code? Maybe add some `alert()` at the beginning.

Comment: I've inserted the alert at the top of the jquery file and isn't displayed when I reload the page. Also in the network when I click on the jquery.js I get statut 200 so this is loaded correctly? 'Cause In the response there's page not found.

Comment: is your alert in the loaded `.js`? If not, make sure it really is your file that is loaded.

Comment: Yeah but when I see the response tab in the network I get page not found, I don't see any js code as the demo provided. Maybe the path is wrong?

Comment: seems like it. Try `<?php echo $base_url; ?>third_party/js/jquery.js`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91905/discussion-between-dillinger-and-t3-h40).